# Autolink not working on react-native 0.63.4 and react-native-localize

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, localization

I am learning how internationalization works on React Native. To do so I am using expo.
I am using this library:
https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-localize

When I test it on the web browser it works perfectly but when I do so in my Android physical device, it does not work. Apparently the linking of react-native-localize is not working. I get this error:

```
Error: react-native-localize: NativeModule.RNLocalize is null. To fix this issue try these steps:
• Run `react-native link react-native-localize` in the project root.
• Rebuild and re-run the app.
• If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then rebuild and re-run the app. You may also need to re-open Xcode to get the new pods.
• Check that the library was linked correctly when you used the link command by running through the manual installation instructions in the README.
• If you are getting this error while unit testing you need to mock the native module. Follow the guide in the README.
• If none of these fix the issue, please open an issue on the Github repository: https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-localize
```

Then if I run `react-native link react-native-localize` it shows a warning that this is deprecated and it does not work.

On my package.json I have this versions for the dependancies localize and react-native:

```
"react-native-localize": "^2.0.1",
"react-native": "~0.63.4",
```

It is supposed for react-native higher than 0.60 linking should be done automatically.

If any further information is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try by running the project again by npx react-native run-android command.

**If you are using the iOS Device then:**

cd ios && pod install
npx react-native run-ios
if still not works try installing the npm package again and follow the documentation.

Comment: also react-native run-android works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
npx react-native link react-native-localize
```

instead of

```
react-native link react-native-localize
```

hope so it will help you